# Alternate editor for RefineryCMS

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, refinerycms, rich-text-editor

I think the build in editor isn't really that great and I think about changing it into something different.

Is there any complete solution with one of the rich javascript editors available? Basicly it should be fairly easy to replace the editor with something else, as it just generates html. One thing which can a bit more difficult is related to images. You can pull image from ones uploaded before and insert it into text.

Do you have any idea how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Currently we are a bit bound to WYMeditor (dialogues etc), which is something we're going to be looking into in the next few months.

WYMeditor is pretty awesome, though, if you're letting clients loose on a system where they could potentially insert some Very Bad HTML WYMeditor is good at reducing this risk. But that's another discussion.